# unit testing in julia notebook using Base.test not defined

Tags: unit-testing, julia

I am running the julia notebook by running the following from inside the Julia command line.

```
using IJulia
notebook()
```

I want to be a good programmer so I first start writing some unit tests before I start writing some actual code. These show different results compared to what the docs tell me to expect.

Code:

```
using Base.test 
@test 1 == 1
@test 1 == 0
```

Output:

```
test not defined
while loading In[272], in expression starting on line 1
```

It seems that Base.test doesn't exist. Do I need to install it even though it belongs to the Base?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It appears that while most examples describe accessing unit tests through

```
using Base.Test
```

in more recent versions of Julia, you may not need to identify the Base package and can import the unit test macros through

```
using Test
```

Answer (score 3):

Its `Base.Test`, not `Base.test` - the error is from the `using` line, not the subsequent lines, in case that was confusing.